# Anylogic/ How can I turn animation off?

Tags: anylogic, non-interactive

I'm doing some experiments using Anylogic7, and have two questions.

1. Can running times of simulation runs be shortened (i.e., running faster) by turning off animation?
2. If it is true, how can I turn off animation? I haven't found 'non-interactive mode'.

Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple different types of [experiments](https://anylogic.help/anylogic/experiments/index.html) within AnyLogic, many of which can be run with minimal animation, and are usually faster.

You can create a new experiment by:

```
Project > Right Click > New > Experiment
```

The one you choose will depend on what your objective is.

Comment: I'll try. Thanks.